# How to login/ssh into Dataflow VM workers in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a dataflow job. How to define metatags for it to login via sss into dataflow workers in GCP?

Answer (score 1):

If you [go to the Compute Engine section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nvvs0.png) in your GCP console, you will be able to find a list of VMs running.

A set of workers for a Dataflow job will run under the same instance group, and next to each instance, you can see a button with a set of options to SSH into it:

[image: SSH into Dataflow worker]

Comment: when clicked on SSH, it says "Connecting.. Transferring SSH keys to the VM." and then an error message comes saying "Connection Failed
You cannot connect to the VM instance because of an unexpected error. Wait a few moments and then try again. (#13)".

Comment: once inside the VM, one can also access the docker container the job is running in

Comment: This solutions doesn't work, never connect  to the Dataflow 's worker VM, always return "We are unable to connect to the VMon port 22"